# Resume download after app has been quit

Tags: ios, skmaps

I was wondering whether it was possible to resume a download after the app has been terminated by the user or the OS.

I can see that `SKTDownloadManager` has methods to pause and resume a download. However, these methods only work for current `SKTDownloadObjectHelper`s.
If I pull them out of `SKTDownloadManager.storedDownloadObjects()` *after* the app has been quit and then started again and throw them at `SKTDownloadManager.sharedInstance().resumeDownloadForDownloadHelper()` the manager won't resume the downloads.

I dug a little deeper into the code and that these downloads are not getting restarted is because of a lack of a proper status. `SKTGroupedDownloadOperation.m:87`:

```
if (self.currentRunningGroupedOperation.stateDownloadItem >= SKTMapDownloadItemStatusDownloading) {
     return NO; //cannot start download,isntall, finsihed
}
```

So, my questions is whether it is even possible to resume downloads after the app has been terminated and if so how do I do it. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: We've passed this question to the developer of SKTDownloadManager asking for support

Comment: Hi Ando, any updates?

Comment: See SylviA's answer as it is the correct one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For resuming the download, you should trigger an event in the application:`didFinishLaunching` or after the application restarted:

```
[[SKDownloadManager sharedInstance] tryRestartDownloadsWithDelegate:self andDataSource:self];
```

Comment: Thank you Sylvia for your answer. Any idea why this isn't included in the documentation? http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/iosTools/2.5.0/Classes/SKTDownloadManager.html

Comment: We will make this improvement for the next SDK update- thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Well you can use AFNetworking Classes for that. [AFNetworkingDownloadclasses](https://github.com/steipete/AFDownloadRequestOperation)

Comment: That would certainly be a solution to the problem, however I'm wondering whether there might be a built in functionality from Skobbler/Scout that I may have overlooked.